# Keeping just the hh:mm:ss from a time delta

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a column of timedeltas which have the attributes listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#attributes). I want the output in my pandas table to go from:

```
1 day, 13:54:03.0456
```

to:

```
13:54:03
```

How can I drop the date from this output?

Comment: Not really, I am just looking for hour and smaller for these calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get seconds of the day with `dt.seconds` and then pass that to `pd.Timedelta`:

```
from pandas import Series, date_range
from datetime import timedelta
td = Series(date_range('20130101',periods=4)) - Series(date_range('20121201',periods=4))
td[2] += timedelta(minutes=5,seconds=3)

In [321]: td
Out[321]: 
0   31 days 00:00:00
1   31 days 00:00:00
2   31 days 00:05:03
3   31 days 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [322]: td.dt.seconds.apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(seconds=x))
Out[322]: 
0   00:00:00
1   00:00:00
2   00:05:03
3   00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This seems like a promising solution. However, I have some timedeltas that are NaN - is there a better way of getting around these than error exception?

Comment: You could use `dropna` of `fillna` methods to drop or fill with values what you like

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract the number of days from each Timedelta:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.to_timedelta(np.linspace(0, 10**6, 10), unit='s')})
df.iloc[::3, 0] = pd.NaT
df['B'] = df['A'] - df['A'].values.astype('timedelta64[D]')
# truncate fractional seconds
df['truncated'] = df['B'].values.astype('timedelta64[s]')
# round to nearest second
df['rounded'] = np.asarray(np.round(df['B'].values / np.timedelta64(1, 's')), dtype='timedelta64[s]')
print(df)
```

yields

```
                        A               B  truncated  rounded
0                     NaT             NaT        NaT      NaT
1  1 days 06:51:51.111111 06:51:51.111111   06:51:51 06:51:51
2  2 days 13:43:42.222222 13:43:42.222222   13:43:42 13:43:42
3                     NaT             NaT        NaT      NaT
4  5 days 03:27:24.444444 03:27:24.444444   03:27:24 03:27:24
5  6 days 10:19:15.555556 10:19:15.555556   10:19:15 10:19:16
6                     NaT             NaT        NaT      NaT
7  9 days 00:02:57.777778 00:02:57.777778   00:02:57 00:02:58
8 10 days 06:54:48.888889 06:54:48.888889   06:54:48 06:54:49
9                     NaT             NaT        NaT      NaT
```

Column `A` shows the original Timedelta. Column `B` shows the result after subtracting the whole days. The `truncated` and `rounded` columns shows the result after dropping or rounding off fractional seconds.

Calling `astype('timedelta64[D]')` truncates the NumPy timedelta64s to whole days.
Similarly, calling `astype('timedelta64[s]')` truncates the NumPy timedelta64s to whole seconds. See [the NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) for more on datetime64/timedelta64 arithmetic.

---

An alternative way to subtract the days is to use:

```
df['B'] = df['A'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['A'].dt.days, unit='d')
```

but this turns out to be slower:

```
In [72]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.to_timedelta(np.linspace(0, 10**6, 1000), unit='s')})

In [73]: %timeit df['A'] - df['A'].values.astype('timedelta64[D]')
1000 loops, best of 3: 729 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit df['A'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['A'].dt.days, unit='d')
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

---

An alternative way to round to the nearest second is:

```
df['rounded'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['B'].dt.total_seconds().round(), unit='s')
```

but again this is slower:

```
In [104]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.to_timedelta(np.linspace(0, 10**6, 1000), unit='s')})

In [105]: df['B'] = df['A'] - df['A'].values.astype('timedelta64[D]')

In [106]: %timeit np.asarray(np.round(df['B'].values / np.timedelta64(1, 's')), dtype='timedelta64[s]')
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop

In [107]: %timeit pd.to_timedelta(df['B'].dt.total_seconds().round(), unit='s')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop
```