# Display pandas timedelta in HH:MM:SS format by converting days to hours

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

If I use

```
first_an_last['duration'] = (first_an_last.last_time - first_an_last.first_time)
```

I get

```
0       0 days 04:19:00
1       2 days 04:39:00
2       1 days 06:10:00
```

Which is fine, but I want to display this:

```
0       04:19:00
1       52:39:00
2       30:10:00
```

Of course I can have this:

```
first_an_last['duration'] = (first_an_last.last_time - first_an_last.first_time) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

where I can get

```
0        4.316667
1        52.650000
2        30.166667
```

But I would like to display it formatted as HH:MM:SS regardless of the number of hours as the user do not understand how much minutes (and seconds) is 0.65 hour in this example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping just the hh:mm:ss from a time delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529417/keeping-just-the-hhmmss-from-a-time-delta)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def converter(x):
    hour = x.hour + (x.days * 24)
    hour = hour if hour > 9 else "0"+str(hour)
    minutes = x.minutes if minutes > 9 else "0"+str(minutes)
    seconds = x.seconds if minutes > 9 else "0"+str(seconds)
    return f"{hour}:{minutes}:{seconds}"
```

Considering the column `first_an_last['duration']` is in `timedelta` format

```
first_an_last['duration'] = first_an_last['duration'].apply(lambda x: converter(x.components)
```

if `first_an_last['duration']` is not `timedelta` format, try below one

```
first_an_last['duration'] = first_an_last['duration'].apply(lambda x: converter(pd.to_timedelta(x).components)
```

Let me know your results